# Pass gallery image from MainActivity to another Activity

Tags: android

My `Main2Activity` class

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    ImageView imgView;
    static final String TAG = "Main2Activity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                final Uri uri = data.getData();

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                int nh = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * (1024.0 / bitmap.getWidth()));
                Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1024, nh, true);
                imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(imageView);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(scaled);

                Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(bt_tab3);
                button3.setOnClickListener
                        (new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main3Activity.class);
                        intent.setData(uri).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops! Sorry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the `Main3Activity`

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Uri imageUri = getIntent().getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}
```

How can I show same gallery image in `MainActivity` and another `Activity`?

Comment: Write down code for button click Listener inside Activity and call button.performClick function in on Activity Result. Also declare Uri object globally. You will get desired result.

Comment: It's so simple. just put image `uri` in bundle and get it in the other activity.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand... Would  you like to write Code..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `Button` related codes into `onCreate()` and send `Uri` as `String` using intent `extras`.

**Update `Main2Activity` as below:**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String TAG = "Main2Activity";

    private static int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    ImageView imgView;
    Button button3;

    Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_tab3);

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main3Activity.class); 
                intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                // Get uri
                imageUri = data.getData();

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                int nh = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * (1024.0 / bitmap.getWidth()));
                Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1024, nh, true);
                // Set image
                imgView.setImageBitmap(scaled);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops! Sorry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Get `Uri` as `string` from `intent` and construct `Uri` from `string` using  `Uri.parse()` method.

**Update `Main3Activity` as below:**

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;

    Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            imageUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUri"));
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god!!!!!!! You solve it about i don't  solve for 3days. Thak you very much..:D♥

Comment: Glad to know that. If my answer solves your problem then you can mark this as right answer. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the file path from the uri as `String` like this to `Main3Activity`.

```
button3.setOnClickListener
        (new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main3Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("filePath", uri.getPath());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

And in `Main3Activity` get the data passed from the calling `Activity` like this.

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        File file = new File(getIntent().getStringExtra("filePath"));
        setImageFromFileIntoImageView(file);
    }

    private void setImageFromFileIntoImageView (File imgFile)
        if(imgFile.exists()){
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to add the following permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I write permission too, nevertheless It not show in gallery image in another Activity. Help me..:''(

Answer (score 0):

based on you not accepting previous answers here is a different approach :

first convert your image to byte array like :

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/to/image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

then convert that into string like :

```
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

then from your first activity make an intent and put that string as an extra like:

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(context,Main3Activity.class);
imageIntent.putExtra("image",encodedImage);
startActivity(imageIntent);
```

and after that it is so easy to get this string in the next activity using `getIntent` and then `getExtra`

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for doing that. I'm  touched by your code :D Tanks again